# Getting result of an Activity synchronously

Tags: android, android-activity, ipc

I'd like to start an Activity and get a result synchronously (I own both activities).  Context.startActivityForResult is asynchronous.  And, Instrumentation.startActivitySync only works intra-process.  I would need it to work like startActivitySync, but across processes.

Is there an API to do so ?  If not, which of Android's IPC mechanism would work in a synchronous fashion...or at least I can mimic it to work synchronously ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't.  Nor would Instrumentation be a good idea.  Either put your code in onActivityResult, or (if on a non-main thread) wait on a semaphore after calling startActivity and release the semaphore in onActivityResult.  Then process the result after the semaphore is released.

Comment: So, start the activity, set up a wait, then call notify on that when I receive the response ?  That should work.  My only concern would be getting an ANR because I would not be calling startActivityForResult because I dont want the called Activity closed.  I would have it return the value and catch it in onNewIntent.  Which would then call notifyAll().

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a static variable in the first activity and modify this variable from the second activity? Or a function? Then you can process. Or maybe you have other needs?